# How to send bearer token through header of axios call in react redux

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, authorization, redux, bearer-token

```
  [HttpPost("xxxxxxxxxx")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "xxxxxxxxx")] 
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
        { 
            if (s == null)
            {

            }

        }
```

the above code is attribute Authorize(Roles ="Director"). My application roles are student, Director,Manager. This particular method has to be accessed only by director, and for the above method It is giving me back 401 unauthorized.

```
export function xxxxxxxxxxxx(token, formValues) {

        return axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx`, formValues);

    }
}
```

I am not sure how to send bearer token in header through axios call.

Comment: Did you test without a role in the attribute?

Comment: allow anonymous is working fine.

Comment: Not anonymous, just with [Authorize].

Comment: Authorize also gave me same result 401 unauthorized

Comment: Are you sending the token in the header?

Comment: Nope ,I am just sending srudent object

Answer (score 5):

You just need to pass the Bearer jwt token as the third parameter.

```
axios.post(url, data, {
'headers': {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwtStr
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If sending requests to a Web API controller, you need to send the authorization token in the header **Authorization**, eg : "Bearer xxxxxxxx".

Answer (score 0):

You can try configuring it in API const declaration like this:

apiClient.ts content:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const token = 'POINT YOUR TOKEN LOCATION HERE'

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3333'
});

axios.defaults.headers = {
  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
}

export default api;
```