# Redux toolkit Bearer token undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

Error: authorization bearer undefined is shown in the browser on the .
Here is my [image: Snapshot of request header]
Here is my code of useEffect of OrderScreen.js Here I have tried to dispatch  check if user have value or not if not redirect them to /login which is login page. I am redirecting to login page because from use state i am not getting any value.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

    const { orders, isLoading, isError, message } = useSelector(
        (state) => state.orders,
    )
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isError) {
            toast.error(message)
        }

        if (!user && !user.isAdmin) {
            navigate('/login')
        }

        dispatch(getOrder())

        return () => {
            dispatch(reset())
        }
    }, [user, isError, message, dispatch, navigate])
```

`

Here is my orderSlice. for the getOrder Function `

```
const initialState = {
    orders: [],
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: '',
}

export const getOrder = createAsyncThunk(
    'orders/getOrder',
    async (_, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token
            return await orderService.getOrder(token)
        } catch (error) {
            const message =
                (error.response &&
                    error.response.data &&
                    error.response.data.message) ||
                error.message ||
                error.toString()
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
        }
    },
)
```

`

Here is my orderService.js `

```
const getOrder = async (token) => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    }

    const response = await axios.get(API_URL, config)
    return response.data
}
```

`
I tried to solve from these stacks

1. [Authorization Bearer Token Header in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164935/authorization-bearer-token-header-in-javascript)
2. [How to send bearer token through header of axios call in react redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270024/how-to-send-bearer-token-through-header-of-axios-call-in-react-redux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pass the token as first argument of your thunk function ( currently "_") to make sure it is not undefined. Also, you can use a debugger to know the actual state of the global store (or simply log it in your component).

And lastly, try to log what returns the thunkApi.getState() function.

Comment: `const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token` - the `token` has the value of`undefied`. Debug or console log to find out why your ```user.token is undefined```

Comment: Thank you logging my state helped me debug the problem.